# Git master branch is n commits behind development

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am getting error as "Merge Conflicts" while trying to merge my development branch with master branch and my master branch is showing 38 commits behind development branch.

How to resolve this issue in GIT

Comment: Put simply, merge conflicts arise because there is different data on the same line number in two different branches. When you did the `git merge` or `git pull` (which is just shorthand for `git fetch` and then `git merge`), git is just saying that you have to resolve some differences between the two branches before you can commit the result. See [this explanation on merge conflicts in git](https://imagej.net/Git_Conflicts)

Comment: Do you use any GUI client like `Sourcetree`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

If you're alone and sure that's you won't lose anything important on master, try:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin
$ git merge -X theirs <developing-branch-name>
```